# What is the Caio Hack?

Tags: css

I was playing around right-clicking my line numbers in Dreamweaver, trying to bookmark a line.

I noticed this menu entry:

[image]

What is the Caio Hack? With `alert('hi');` highlighted, this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Try this, for an explanation : http://bit.ly/14zJYNS

Comment: Not sure this really warranted its own (self-answered) question.

Comment: I agree with @MattBall, I am not against answering your own questions, but a simple Google search for this can provide you with more information then what you can (will) put in your post

Comment: @musefan I was curious to what the option did. Naturally, being an avid SO user, I searched SO instead of Google. No matches. That's why I posted the question & answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old CSS hack.

> "Caio Hack is a simple CSS comments-based hack used in 'inline' and
>   'external' CSS declarations to hide information from Netscape 4"

For example, this code hides the .foo2 selector to Netscape 4:

```
.foo1
{
  color: green;
  background-color: yellow;
}
/*/*/
.foo2
{
  color: red;<code></code>
}
/* */
.foo3
{
  color: blue;
}
```

Source: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets/Hacks_and_Filters/Caio_Hack

Answer (score 2):

The Caio Hack is named after its discoverer, Caio Chassot.

It is a CSS hack for hiding rules from Netscape 4, exploiting a bug in NN4's parser.

By opening a comment using `/*/*/`, all subsequent CSS would be ignored by NN, because it thinks the comment didn't close.

To end the block, you'd use `/* */`.

For example:

```
.foo1
{
  color: green;
  background-color: yellow;
}
/*/*/
.foo2
{
  color: red;
}
/* */
.foo3
{
  color: blue;
}
```

More info at:

- [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets/Hacks_and_Filters/Caio_Hack)
- [CSS Discuss](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Caio_Hack)

Answer (score -1):

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Caio_Hack

It hides CSS codes from Netscape4 and sometimes Opera.